# Can I disable corporate monitoring by disabling my network connection?

Tags: web-browser, monitoring, web

Can my activities be traced if the Ethernet cable is not connected? If I disconnect the company's Ethernet cable & connect my PC to tethering, will the browser history be still captured once I connect the Ethernet cable & remove my tethering?

Comment: You need to give much more context for us to help you. Was your HP a Windows laptop? I assume the tethering was to a mobile, who owns that mobile? Who configured the HP? Etc...

Comment: There is no way for us to know if your company has installed agents on your machine to log all this activity. Ask your IT department.

Comment: Your company trusts you to maintain your system correctly, within their rules and guidelines. Even if there were a way to avoid this when using company assets, trying to do so makes you a bad employee.

Answer (score 2):

If your company asset is configured to use a company-owned cloud proxy when off corporate network, your activities will still be tracked in near-time.

If your company gathers logs and forensics from remote endpoints, it may queue up your data until it is back on network, reachable by the company syslog server or SIEM.